# Plotting a box plot with subcategories in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a box plot with subcategories using ggplot2.

For example,

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot()
```

gives me 3 boxplots corresponding to "cyl"  values (4,6,8).

Now I want to split each boxplot into two boxplots by "am" variable (0 or 1). 
Is there a way to make it nice so that I will still have a plot with 3 main categories defined by "cyl", but then each will consist of two boxplots defined by "am" variable.

Comment: Questions like this belong on [SO]. If you can wait, we will migrate this for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use facets or just map `am` in your aesthetics for example to fill color:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill=factor(am))) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```